# Send messages to AWS SQS using JMeter

Tags: jmeter, amazon-sqs

I want to test the scenarios of sending message to AWS SQS from Jmeter. But i dont find any relevant procedure to do it. I came to  know about awsmaster plugin but after installing it, it doesnot get installed(seems like a corrupted version)

I am trying with Custom code but there also, the attribute builder() of "sqs client" shows a warning as **"This static method of interface SqsClient can only be accessed as SqsClient.builder"**

So, can someone please guide how to send messages to SQS queue using Jmeter and the steps.Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you're willing to copy and paste the code to initialize the SqsClient you can take a look at [AWS Java SDK Examples repository](https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-doc-sdk-examples/tree/main/javav2/example_code/sqs#readme):

```
SqsClient sqsClient = SqsClient.builder()
  .region(Region.US_WEST_2)
  .credentialsProvider(ProfileCredentialsProvider.create())
  .build();
```

Then you can send the message like it's described [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/code-library/latest/ug/sqs_example_sqs_SendMessage_section.html):

```
   CreateQueueRequest request = CreateQueueRequest.builder()
       .queueName(queueName)
       .build();
   sqsClient.createQueue(request);

   GetQueueUrlRequest getQueueRequest = GetQueueUrlRequest.builder()
       .queueName(queueName)
       .build();

   String queueUrl = sqsClient.getQueueUrl(getQueueRequest).queueUrl();
   SendMessageRequest sendMsgRequest = SendMessageRequest.builder()
       .queueUrl(queueUrl)
       .messageBody(message)
       .delaySeconds(5)
       .build();

   sqsClient.sendMessage(sendMsgRequest);
```

The code can be placed in i.e. [JSR223 Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler), use [Groovy](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-groovy) as the scripting language.

Make sure to add necessary [import statements](https://groovy-lang.org/structure.html#_imports), copy AWS Java SDK with all its dependencies to [JMeter classpath](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#classpath) and restart JMeter to pick up the jars.